How can I get the Current Page is Last Page event in Webview in Kotlin?
I am loading Pdf file from URL into web view with this
val doc = "<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${pdfFile}&embedded=true' width='100%' height='100%' style='border: none;'></iframe>"

I have loaded the PDF file into Webview like below and it successfully loaded,
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON

webView.loadData(doc, "text/html", "UTF-8")

But I want the an event for current page is last page at that time I need to show the Two buttons at bottom but I don't know how can I get that event. Can someone please help me with this.
